# Neo4j2.0 How to get nodes by labels and properties

Tags: neo4j

i am using Neo4j 2.0 . I 've created many nodes with Label X  and an unique property Y. I mean, this property Y is different for different nodes with Label X.

I'm using Embedded-neo4j. How can we get a node using Java API given the label X and property Y. How can U get a reference to the node?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a Cypher query using the Java API:

```
match (n:X {Y:"propertyValue"}) return n
```

where X is the label name and Y is the property name

Answer (score 1):

In  Neo4j 2.1.6 using Embedded, it can be done as :

```
Iterable<Node> lNodes =database.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label("LabelInString"), "Name of Propery", lPropertyValue);
```

where database is instance of GraphDatabaseService.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean unique property Y or unique property value of attrib Y in a node. In case you have unique properties Y in nodes label X you can do below

```
GraphDatabaseService graphService =new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphService);
String label = "X";
String property ="Y";
String query = "MATCH (n:"+label+") WHERE has(n."+property+") return n";
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query);
ResourceIterator<Node> resultIterator = result.columnAs("n");
Node resultNode = null;
if(resultIterator.hasNext()){
   resultNode = resultIterator.next();
}
```